# How many time to be context-switched?

Tags: linux, c, scheduling, real-time

Let's assume that we're in a real-time program where scheduler's context-switches might interfere our performance.
Suppose I need to do many consecutive (but optional) operations of the same type in every execution of a timer-oriented signal handler -->
Could I check how much time left until my thread get context-switched? [...] and then I can jump some operations for a better performance at all.
If yes, how can I do it (in C code)?